# The exported image does not match the preview I see whilst editing

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, images, photoshop-effects, photo-editing

I basically exported an image after editing and found that it does not match the one I see while editing.

This is the image while editing:
[image]

This is the preview in the export window:
[image]

And the exported image:
[image]

The exported image is much brighter. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you viewing the image at 100% when editing?

Comment: No. I zoom in back and forth while I am but most of the time I am at 66.67%.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to GDSE. What happens if you use *File > Save As*, and choose PNG as the format, or use *File > Export > Save for Web (Legacy)*?

Comment: When exported with PNG as the format, then that would be the third image above. I tried "save for web (legacy)" and it worked. Thanks :) But do you perhaps know why this problem disappears only when the latter option is chosen?

Comment: @JeoLuntayan - I've added an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Is the person on a different layer? And does that / those layers have some smart filter / effect associated with it? Perhaps it needs flattening / merging BEFORE you try to export? Sometimes going from the main screen to exporting does strange things on flattening / export?

Comment: Yes, the person is a different layer. The smart filters/ effects associated with it would be the Curves (clipped to the person) and a Color Lookup which affects all layers. I tried flattening/ merging it before exporting it but it unfortunately did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use *File > Export > Save for Web (Legacy)*

As for why *Export As* is giving you this problem, that's something only Adobe can really answer. It looks like a bug to me. Perhaps report it to Adobe.

Note that *Save for Web* is the older (legacy) way of exporting. *Export As* is a more recent innovation.

In recent years it has unfortunately become somewhat typical of Adobe to try to make something new to replace an older function that already works just fine, and then mess up the implementation in some way.